# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) while using Predict function

Tags: regression, glm, poisson

When I try to run predict() on the dataset, it keeps giving me error -
*Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'LoanRange' not found*

Here is the part of dataset -

`LoanRange    Loan.Type    N   WAFICO  WALTV  WAOrigRev WAPTValue
1         0-99999 Conventional  109 722.5216 63.55385  6068.239 0.6031879
2         0-99999          FHA   30 696.6348 80.00100  7129.650 0.5623650
3         0-99999           VA   13 698.6986 74.40525  7838.894 0.4892977
4   100000-149999 Conventional  860 731.2333 68.25817  6438.330 0.5962638
5   100000-149999          FHA  285 673.2256 82.42225  8145.068 0.5211495
6   100000-149999           VA  125 704.1686 87.71306  8911.461 0.5020074
7   150000-199999 Conventional 1291 738.7164 70.08944  8125.979 0.6045117
8   150000-199999          FHA  403 672.0891 84.65318 10112.192 0.5199632
9   150000-199999           VA  195 694.1885 90.77495 10909.393 0.5250807
10  200000-249999 Conventional 1162 740.8614 70.65027  8832.563 0.6111419
11  200000-249999          FHA  348 667.6291 85.13457 11013.856 0.5374226
12  200000-249999           VA  221 702.9796 91.76759 11753.642 0.5078298
13  250000-299999 Conventional  948 742.0405 72.22742  9903.160 0.6106858`

Following is the code used for predicting count data **N** after determining the overdispersion-

```
model2=glm(N~Loan.Type+WAFICO+WALTV+WAOrigRev+WAPTValue, family=quasipoisson(link = "log"), data = DF)
summary(model2)
```

This is what I have done to create a sequence of count and use predict function-

```
countaxis <- seq (0,1500,150)
Y <- predict(model2, list(N=countaxis, type = "response")
```

At this step, I get the error -

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'LoanRange' not found
```

Can someone please point me where is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what exactly you are trying to predict. You are providing the `predict` function values of `N` (via `countaxis`), but in fact the way you set up your model, `N` is your response variable and the remaining variables are the predictors. That's why R is asking for `LoanRange`. It actually needs values for `LoanRange, Loan.Type, ..., WAPTValue` in order to predict `N`. So you need to feed `predict` inputs that let the model try to predict `N`.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
# create some fake data to predict N
newdata1 = data.frame(rbind(c("0-99999", "Conventional", 722.5216, 63.55385,  6068.239, 0.6031879),
                            c("150000-199999", "VA", 12.5216, 3.55385,  60.239, 0.0031879)))
colnames(newdata1) = c("LoanRange" ,"Loan.Type", "WAFICO"  ,"WALTV" , "WAOrigRev" ,"WAPTValue")

# ensure that numeric variables are indeed numeric and not factors
newdata1$WAFICO = as.numeric(as.character(newdata1$WAFICO))
newdata1$WALTV = as.numeric(as.character(newdata1$WALTV))
newdata1$WAPTValue = as.numeric(as.character(newdata1$WAPTValue))
newdata1$WAOrigRev = as.numeric(as.character(newdata1$WAOrigRev))

# make predictions - this will output values of N
predict(model2, newdata = newdata1, type = "response")
```